# How to clean Detox CLI logs?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, e2e-testing, detox

I would like to remove all the clutter from test logs. My cli becomes full of UI elements descriptions while testing in IOS, I haven't tried it in Android yet. It's very annoying to scroll back to the top to find an useful error message after a test suit finishes running. I've already tried all values for the flag -l/--loglevel but no luck.

It looks like this

```
...Useful messages here

THIS IS THE CLUTTER => Hierarchy: <UIWindow:0x7f9bbd5236f0; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>
      |--<RCTRootView:0x7f9bbd434f10; AX=N; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>

      |  |--<RCTRootContentView:0x7f9bbd51b4e0; AX=N; AX.label='Foo Bar CREATE ACCOUNT LOGIN Go to home Welcome!  Tap here to login   Foo Bar  Foo Bar  Hey, welcome back!  E-mail  Password    Incorrect email or password. LOGIN Register Reset password Login'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>

      |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7f9bbd41a840; AX=N; AX.label='Foo Bar CREATE ACCOUNT LOGIN Go to home Welcome!  Tap here to login   Foo Bar  Foo Bar  Hey, welcome back!  E-mail  Password    Incorrect email or password. LOGIN Register Reset password Login'; AX.frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; AX.activationPoint={187.5, 333.5}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; opaque; alpha=1>

      |  |  |  |--<RCTView:0x7f9bbd519410; AX=N; AX.label='Foo bar...

... and so on
```

[An image from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQJkf.png)

Comment: One way is to make the hierarchy in your app smaller. I assure you, your users will love you for it.